# Emulate Python shell's "return value" behaviour

Tags: python, compilation, exec, eval, read-eval-print-loop

Let's imagine I have a JSON list of Python strings to evaluate. For example, maybe I am building a client-server Python GUI.

One convenient thing about the regular Python interpreter is that it shows the "pseudo-return value" of each line, like this:

```
 $ python3 -c "import code; code.interact()"
 Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:03) 
 (InteractiveConsole)
 >>> import os; os.curdir
 '.'
```

I didn't have to ask to print out the '.'. It just did it.

Under the covers, one can see that this is implemented with the exec() function:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/800a35c623bbcdb5793c7d7a4974524286311479/Lib/code.py#L90

```
    try:
        exec(code, self.locals)
    except SystemExit:
        raise
    except:
        self.showtraceback()
```

The weird thing is that there is no explicit instruction there to output the result of the exec(). And yet we can see that it does output it.

We can see that this behaviour is very context specific like this:

```
$ echo "5" | python3 -c "import code; code.interact()"
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:03) 
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> 5
>>> 
now exiting InteractiveConsole...
enter code here
```

I assume that if I dig into the C code I will see that it is querying its context to see whether to output the value or not. But it wouldn't answer my main question, which is how to emulate this behaviour in an arbitrary context.

How can I can I execute and get the "pseudo-return value" from a Python string, regardless of whether the string represents an expression or a statement?

Comment: There may be something in the [`code`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#module-code) module (or its source code) that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python compiler has a [flag to keep track of whether Python is being run in interactive mode](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ee40e4b8563e6e1bc2bfb267da5ffc9a2293318d/Python/compile.c#L165).

If this flag is set, when the compiler visits a statement node in the AST, it [emits an extra `PRINT_EXPR` opcode](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ee40e4b8563e6e1bc2bfb267da5ffc9a2293318d/Python/compile.c#L3360).

The interpreter [executes `PRINT_EXPR`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b5cc2089cc354469f12eabc7ba54280e85fdd6dc/Python/ceval.c#L2038) by popping the result of the expression off the stack and passing it as an argument to [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook). The displayhook prints the `repr` of this value to stdout, unless the value is None. It also assigns the value to `builtins._`.

(I guess the reason why the behavior is different when you pipe a command to Python is that then it is not in interactive mode.)

So as long as you are running Python in interactive mode, you can read the value of the `_` builtin after running code with the `exec` builtin.

Comment: I gave you the checkmark because you're close to answering my whole question. My main question was "how to emulate this behaviour in an arbitrary context" which I can now rephrase based on your answer to "can I fake interactive mode?" I guess failing that I could rewrite the AST to add PRINT_EXPR and hack my own displayhook.